# Why does the cable at point B carry no weight?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, statics

[image]

Roughly translated from Dutch;

> "The engine has a weight of 4250 N. Determine the forces in each of the chains (in point A, B and C) the engine is hanging from. The measurements of the hooks can be neglected, and thus considered to be points. The vertical measurements of the bar can be  neglected as well. The bar can thus be considered as a line"

According to the solution of the textbook, the chain in point B carries no weight (0 N). Why/How is that? It may 'look like' the weight of the engine 'should' equally be distributed in chain A and C, but what's the logical and insightful explanation for that? Because according to me, it would be perfectly possible for half of the weight of the engine to be carried by chain C (on the right side), and the other half (on the left side) to be carried by chain A and partially by chain B as well, regardless of the differences in angles.

In other words: What's the proof that chain B does not carry any weight?

Comment: Have you drawn a free-body diagram? Have you examined the symmetry of the system?

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the general principles of statics:  the net force on the beam (in the horizontal direction and the vertical direction) must be zero, and the net torque (moment) about an arbitrary point must be zero.  In principle, this gives you three equations (horizontal force, vertical force, torque) and three unknowns (the magnitudes $F_A$, $F_B$, $F_C$). You can then solve for the magnitudes of the forces.  When you do, you find that the equations imply that $F_B = 0$.

Unfortunately, while this method is "logical", it's not particularly "insightful".  Looking at the equations, the result that $F_B = 0$ seems to stem from the fact that $\vec{F}_A$ and $\vec{F}_C$ have opposite angles and equal lever arms.  But beyond that, I don't know of an intuitive way to see why this is true.